# Is it possible to pass a JSON body along with hx-post through an attribute?

Tags: htmx

As per title, is it possible to pass a JSON body along with hx-post through an attribute? Or do I have to make it a form to pass data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with the official **json-enc** extension, which "*encodes parameters in JSON format instead of url format.*"

https://htmx.org/extensions/json-enc/

### Usage

`<div hx-post='/test' hx-ext='json-enc'>click me</div>`